# Does the method "parse" of DocumentBuilder put the whole XML file into memory?

Tags: java, xml

I'm building a Java application that will have a big XML file which will contain lots of information. I will also have another file - probably binary - that will have indexes to organize that XML file. So, for example, if the XML file has 1000 registers and accessing the binary file I find out that I want to load the register number 687, my idea was loading it directly from de XML file without the need to load the whole XML file into memory.

My first idea was use the Java DOM (Document Object Model) to work with the XML. To parse a XML file into Java Objects, I read that the best method to use is DocumentBuilder's method **parse**, which returns a tree representing the XML file.

So, my question is: When I use this method, it will have to load the whole XML file into memory to parse the file or it will do it slowly depending on which parts of the file I need to use in my program?

Sorry if I made dumb questions, any kind of help/advice is welcome! Remember that my objective is to access the disk the fewest times possible! Thanks!!

Comment: Short answer is, yes, a DOM is an in memory representation of the XML

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thanks for the answer. Then, do you know a good way to do what I need to do? Loading the whole XML file into memory is not what I'm looking for

Comment: Assuming you want random access to the data within the XML file, you will need to map the content somehow into memory, you could use a SAX parser and build your own lightweight model.  If you don't need random access to the XML, you could use the SAX parser as well and load the information from the binary file as the XML file is been parsed